# Move last array string to end of second last array string

Tags: php, arrays, merge, element, implode

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    0 => "a,b",
    1 => "c,d",
    2 => "e,f",
    3 => "g,h", 
);
```

I would like to merge the last two array elements (2 and 3) into a one like this:

```
$array = array(
    0 => "a,b",
    1 => "c,d",
    2 => "e,f,g,h", 
);
```

How can I do it using PHP?

Comment: Is it always the last 2 elements?

Comment: yes. It is always the last two elements.

Comment: Both answers contain solutions for the case that it is always the last two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove tow last items by array_splice and add implode of them

```
$temp = array_splice($array,-2); 
$result = array_merge($array, (array) implode(',', $temp));
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce9af689203f83985433805a57c97eee523dc54f)

As @Nick mentioned, you can do it by

```
$temp = array_splice($array,-2); 
$array[] = implode(',', $temp);
```

Comment: You already did change the source array with `array_splice`. That's why I made my suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use `array_pop()` to remove the last 2 elements, then concatenate them, then add them back to the original array.

```
$array = array(
    0 => "a,b",
    1 => "c,d",
    2 => "e,f",
    3 => "g,h", 
);

$element3 = array_pop($array); //grab value of the last element, and remove it from the array.
$element2 = array_pop($array); 

$array[] = "$element2,$element3";
```

this will always work if it's always supposed to be the last 2 elements.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a one-liner that unconditionally pushes that joined strings of the last two elements after consuming them with `array_splice()`. In other words, the last two elements are removed, joined, then re-pushed into the array as a single element.

The `$temp` variable in @solash58's answer is not necessary -- the consumption of the last two elements will occur before the auto-incremented index is generated.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ttUPu))

```
$array = [
    0 => "a,b",
    1 => "c,d",
    2 => "e,f",
    3 => "g,h", 
];

$array[] = implode(",", array_splice($array, -2));
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'a,b',
  1 => 'c,d',
  2 => 'e,f,g,h',
)
```